# Websphere wsdl server binding issue with second WAR file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wsdl, ejb, websphere

Earlier we had one application let's say abc.ear on which JAX-RPC always worked fine. Now we have one more application.

```
Previous Scenario - 
abc.ear
    -first.war
    -beans.jar

Current Scenario - 
abc.ear
    -first.war
    -beans.jar
    -second.war
```

And here the problem comes. After deploying in **websphere**, wsdl gets generated for second.war not for the first.war.

What I notice in application.xml, we have entries for both WARs and WSDL is getting generated always for second entry.

Application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application id="Application_ID" version="1.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/application_1_4.xsd">
    <display-name>abc</display-name>
    <module id="WebModule_1049898749936">
        <web>
            <web-uri>first.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/firstContext</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
     <module id="WebModule_1049898749937">
        <web>
            <web-uri>second.war</web-uri>
            <context-root>/secondContext</context-root>
        </web>
    </module>
    <module id="EjbModule_1049898671780">
        <ejb>beans.jar</ejb>
    </module>
    <security-role id="SecurityRole_1049898749936">
        <description>abcSecurityRole</description>
        <role-name>abcSecurityRole</role-name>
    </security-role>
</application>
```

Whenever I'm accessing WSDL service for first context /firstContext/services, localhost and port name gets resolved to server name and port.

```
<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:9081/firstContext/services/WsSessionEJBEndPointBean"/>
```

But localhost and port is not getting resolved for secondContext when WSDL service is getting accessed. Am I missing any entry anywhere?

Is it due to routerModule not getting generated in ibm-webservices-bnd.xmi for second.war? I had added it manually.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<com.ibm.etools.webservice.wsbnd:WSBinding xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:com.ibm.etools.webservice.wsbnd="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0.2/wsbnd.xmi" xmi:id="WSBinding_1161041065182">
  <wsdescBindings xmi:id="WSDescBinding_1354375783544" wsDescNameLink="WsSessionEJBEndPointBeanService">
    <pcBindings xmi:id="PCBinding_1354375783544" pcNameLink="WsSessionEJBEndPointBean"/>
  </wsdescBindings>
  <routerModules xmi:id="RouterModule_1161041070381" transport="http" name="first.war"/>
  <routerModules xmi:id="RouterModule_1161041070381" transport="http" name="second.war"/>
</com.ibm.etools.webservice.wsbnd:WSBinding>
```

Also is it possible to have twi different resource modules having same transport?

Comment: You seem to be using the same `xmi:id="RouterModule_1161041070381"` for both modules. I suspect that's relevant.

Comment: @dbreaux How can we generate new router module in ibm-webservices-bnd.xmi?

Comment: I honestly don't know. IDs seem to be only generated by tooling, so that's where I'd be looking.